# adb command not found

Tags: android, macos, terminal, adb

I need to run an `adb forward` command before I could use the *ezkeyboard* application which allows user to type on the phone using browser.

When I run `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` command I get the `adb command not found` error message.

I can run `android` command from terminal. Why `adb` is not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901692/1778421

Comment: @AlexP. This post is older than the one you linked + already solved ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Make sure `adb` is in your user's **$PATH** variable.

**or**

You can try to locate it with `whereis` and run it with `./adb`

Comment: ./adb would only work if the current directory (which is what . is shorthand for) is the location of the adb program.  Otherwise it would be /some/path/found/by/wheris/adb

Comment: Yes I know :-) that's what I meant with finding it and running it from there

Comment: export to $Path in your ~/bashrc

Comment: could try ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: could try `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` (in Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 415):

> **In my case with Android Studio 1.1.0 path was this**

`/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

**Add the following to `~/.bash_profile`**

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

**Then run**

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

to load a profile in a current terminal session, or just reopen a terminal

If you are using more modern **Z Shell** instead of **Bash**, put it in `~/.zprofile` instead.

Comment: I also need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` to make it work

Comment: @Gowtham Sooryaraj those paths are where the tools are located. Adding them to the PATH variable of your env allows you to access the tools (adb here) whithout the need to give the full path of its location (~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb). When you type adb in your terminal, its seeks a similar tool in all the paths of the env PATH variable. I hope it helps :)

Comment: I have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` all the time, what does it do?

Comment: @TylerPfaff it reloads your shell profile. Closing your terminal and reopening it has the same effect.

Comment: On Debian, using Arctic Fox, its: `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb <remaining-command-parts>` to run an adb command with out it added to path (that's its latest location). So you'll want to `export PATH=~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`.  Definitely run a `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`, depending on where you put it, if you don't want to restart your terminal.

Comment: Append values to `.zprofile` file for those who use zsh

Answer (score 224):

Is adb installed? To check, run the following command in Terminal:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

If that prints output, skip these following install steps and go straight to the final Terminal command I list:

1. Launch Android Studio
2. Launch SDK Manager via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
3. Check Android SDK Platform-Tools

Run the following command on your Mac and restart your Terminal session:

```
echo export "PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Note: If you've switched to zsh, the above command should use `.zshenv` rather than `.bash_profile`

Comment: Thank you very much! For zsh your answer with .zshenv worked for me while other answer suggesting .zshrc didn't.

Answer (score 91):

I am using Mac 10.11.1 and using android studio 1.5,
I have my adb 
"/Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

Now edit you bash_profile

```
emacs ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line to your bash_profile, and replace the user-name with your username

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/user-name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
```

save and close.
Run this command to reload your bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Every time I open new terminal it still shows "adb not found". I have to "source" it again before I can use it. Is there any permenant solution?

Answer (score 72):

This is the easiest way and will provide automatic updates.

1. install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

   ```
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install adb

   ```
    brew install --cask android-platform-tools
   ```
3. Start using adb

   ```
    adb devices
   ```

Comment: brew install --cask android-platform-tools in 2021

Comment: does this set the path as well?

Comment: This works in 2023  UPVOTE for best/easiest answer! And yes, it automatically sets the path.

Answer (score 69):

From the file android-sdks/tools/adb_has_moved.txt:

> The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/
>
> If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD
>   Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK
>   Platform-tools"
>
> Please also update your PATH environment variable to include the
>   platform-tools/ directory, so you can execute adb from any location.

so on UNIX do something like:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/android-sdks/platform-tools`

Comment: Selected answer should be edited/completed with this, because adb moved for a long time and the adb_has_moved.txt is not there anymore

Answer (score 26):

Type the below command in terminal:

> nano .bash_profile

And add the following lines (replace USERNAME with your own user name).

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools 
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Close the text editor, and then enter the command below:

> source .bash_profile

Comment: The last command is what allowed me to run adb from anywhere in the console. That final tweak was missing in other answers

Answer (score 25):

### This solution is for Mac:

Considering you have already downloaded SDK platform tools & trying to set **adb** path:

If you want to check the SDK is available or not, just check it by following this path:
User > Library (Hidden folder) > Android > sdk > platform-tools > `adb`

[image: SDK PATH IMAGE]

To set the PATH for the adb command on a macOS system, firstly need to edit your shell configuration file. The default shell on macOS is **Bash** or **Zash**.
If you're using **Bash**, so you will need to edit the **~/.bash_profile** file otherwise edit **~/.zprofile** in your home directory.

## Here's how to do it:

### By Terminal:

1. Open a terminal window and enter the following command:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
nano ~/.zprofile
```

This will open the **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zprofile** file in the Nano text editor.

2. Add the following line to the file:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Press `Ctrl+X` to exit the Nano editor, then press `Y` to save the changes and `Enter` to confirm the filename.

3. Run the following command to reload your shell configuration:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

After you have set the PATH for adb, you should be able to run the adb command from any terminal window.

---

### By Manual:

1. Go to the `Home` directory & tap `command` + `shift` + `.` (on Mac system/laptop)
   [image: View IMAGE]
2. Search file **~/.bash_profile** or **~/.zprofile** & open it.
   [image: View IMAGE]
3. Add required path & save it.
   [image: View IMAGE]

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

4. Run the following command to reload your shell configuration:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

After you have set the PATH for adb, you should be able to run the adb command from any terminal window.

Comment: After complete this process, Just run command in the terminal: `adb version`

Comment: Restart the machine, if above things are not working.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to edit `PATH` variable, go to the `platform-tools` directory where the `SDK` is installed, and the command is there.

You can use it like this:

1. Go to the directory where you placed the `SDK`:

   `cd /Users/mansour/Library/Developer/Android/sdk/platform-tools`
2. Type the `adb` command with `./` to use it from the current directory.

   `./adb tcpip 5555`

   `./adb devices`

   `./adb connect 192.168.XXX.XXX`

Answer (score 14):

For mac users with zshrc file (who don't have bash profile).

1. Go to your user folder and tap cmd + fn + shift + "." (on Mac laptop keyboard !)
2. Hidden files are visible, open .zhrc file with a Text Editor
3. Paste this line, don't forget to change the username between braces :

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
```

you can save and close the .zhrc

4. Open terminal and reload the file with this :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now you can use adb command lines !

Answer (score 11):

Considering you have already downloaded SDK platform tools. These commands are for MAC users.

This command will set ADB locally. So if you close the terminal and open it again, ADB commands won't work until you run this command again.

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

These commands will set ADB globally. So once you run these commands no need to set them again next time.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: the answer is correct but just if the shell is zsh you have to change .bash_profile to .zshenv

Answer (score 11):

You need to install `adb` first,
the new command (in 2021) is:

`brew install --cask android-platform-tools`

Answer (score 10):

Mac users just open `/Users/(USERNAME)/.bash_profile` this file in a editor.
and add this line to add path.

```
export PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

this is the default path if you install adb via studio. 
and dont forget to change the username in this line.

Comment: export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH should do it, no need to change anything

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was in the `platform-tools` directory but was using command in the wrong way:

```
adb install
```

instead of the right way:

```
./adb install
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need to be in the platform-tools directory. That means your PATH isn’t set correctly and you’d be better off following one of the other answers here.

Answer (score 8):

On my Mac (OS X 10.8.5) I have adb here:

```
~/Library/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
```

So, edit the `$PATH` in your `.bash_profile` and `source` it.

Comment: More recently this is `~/Library/android/sdk/platform-tools/` on macOS.

Answer (score 7):

***+ The reason is:*** you are in the wrong directory (means it doesn't contain adb executor).

***+ The solution is (step by step):***

**1) Find where the adb was installed**. Depend on what OS you are using.

Mac, it could be in: "`~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`"

or

Window, it could be in: "`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\`".

However, in case you could NOT remember this such long directory, you can quickly find it by the command "`find`". Try this in your terminal/ command line, "`find  / -name "platform-tools" 2> /dev/null`" (Note: I didn't test in Window yet, but it works with Mac for sure).

*Explain the find command,

- Please note there is a space before the "/" character --> only find in User directory not all the computer.
- "`2> /dev/null`" --> ignore find results denied by permission. Try the one without this code, you will understand what I mean.

**2) Go to where we installed adb.** There are 3 ways mentioned by many people:

- Change the PATH global param (which I won't recommend) by: "`export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`" which is the directory you got from above. Note, this command won't print any result, if you want to make sure you changed PATH successfully, call "`export | grep PATH`" to see what the PATH is.
- Add more definition for the PATH global param (which I recommend) by: "`export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`" or "`export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`"
- Go to the path we found above by "`cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`"

**3) Use adb:**

- If you change or update the PATH, simply call any adb functions, since you added the PATH as a global param. (e.g: "`adb devices`")
- If you go to the PATH by `cd` command, call adb functions with pre-fix "`./` " (e.g: "`./ adb devices`")

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by install **adb** package. I'm using **Ubuntu**.

```
sudo apt install adb
```

I think this will help to you.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a mac, try this below command.

> source $HOME/.bash_profile

Answer (score 4):

in my case I added the following line in my terminal:

export PATH="/Users/Username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

make sure that you replace "username" with YOUR user name.

hit enter then type 'adb' to see if the error is gone.  if it is, this is what you should see:
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40

...followed by a bunch of commands..and ending with this:
$ADB_TRACE
     comma-separated list of debug info to log:
     all,adb,sockets,packets,rwx,usb,sync,sysdeps,transport,jdwp
 $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS         colon-separated list of keys (files or directories)
 $ANDROID_SERIAL          serial number to connect to (see -s)
 $ANDROID_LOG_TAGS        tags to be used by logcat (see logcat --help)

if you get that, run npm run android again and it should work..

Answer (score 3):

To avoid rewriting the $PATH variables every time you start a terminal, edit your **.bash_profile** (for Macs, it's just **.profile**) file under your home directory (**~/**), and place the export statement somewhere in the file.

Now every time you start terminal, your $PATH variable will be correctly updated. To update the terminal environment immediately after modifying the profile file, type in:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: You should add the appropriate export statement to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
nano /home/user/.bashrc  
export ANDROID_HOME=/psth/to/android/sdk  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

However, this will not work for su/ sudo. If you need to set system-wide variables, you may want to think about adding them to /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, or /etc/environment.

ie:

```
nano /etc/bash.bashrc  
export ANDROID_HOME=/psth/to/android/sdk  
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have adb installed
- To install it you could run the "sudo apt install adb".
- You could also try revoking any USB authorizations on your device and
  try connecting with USB debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

UNABLE TO LOCATE ADB #SOLVED
Simply Download Sdk platform tools.*https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html*
Extract the Downloaded file.
Go to Sdk Manager in Android Studio and copy the link. Go to file Explorer and paste the path for Sdk you copied to view the Sdk files. You will notice that the Adb file is missing, open downloaded file (platform tools) copy contents and replace every content in your Sdk tool file (the file where you noticed adb is missing)and save. You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this is the solving of this problem

1. Make sure you have installed the android SDK. Usually the location of SDK
   is located to this location

   */Users/your-user/Library/Android/sdk*
2. After that **cd** to that directory.
3. Once you are in that directory type this command
   *./platform-tools/adb install your-location-of apk*

Answer (score 1):

if youd dont have adb in folder `android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/` you should install platform tools first. Run `android-sdk-macosx/tools/android` and [Install platform tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzvWz.png) from Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

you have to move the adb command to /bin/ folder

in my case:

```
sudo su
mv /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following command to `.zshrc` file

Open file in terminal using command ->  `vi .zshrc`
Add the android sdk path - > `exportPATH="/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"`

Close the file by -> `Esc + :wq`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***fish***: 
`fish_add_path /Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` 
Or you can add the same to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` 
Might need to re start the shell

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android studio and check if the platform-tools are installed properly.

check if this is giving you the out put

> ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

if Yes, then add this to you Path by vim ~/.zshenv or
echo export "PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH" >> ~/. zshenv

Answer (score 0):

in fish shell (ubuntu 22.04)

1. sudo nano .config/fish/config.fish
2. add line set -gx PATH $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb $PATH;
3. save and celebrate!

Answer (score 0):

Follow These Steps :

I'm using Mac OS (Version Sonama 14.4)

Open the **terminal** and paste this **commands** one by one

**install brew**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**install adb server**

```
brew install --cask android-platform-tools
```

**Start using adb**

```
adb devices
```