# Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh

I'm using zsh terminal, and I'm trying to add a new entry (`/home/david/pear/bin`) to the `PATH` variable. I don't see a reference to the `PATH` variable in my `~/.zshrc` file, but doing `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

So I know that the path variable is being set somewhere.  Where is the `PATH` variable set / modified for the zsh terminal?

Comment: In my opinion, PATH should be manipulated in `.zshenv`, not in `.zshrc`...

Comment: In case anyone else is curious about @Rmano's pointer on using '.zshenv' (as I was), here's [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout?newreg=741ab675789d4b1ba96862d40c2bb2d7) a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 473, accepted):

Here, add this line to `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=/home/david/pear/bin:$PATH
```

**EDIT**: This does work, but [ony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/1008938) above is better, as it takes advantage of the structured interface ZSH provides for variables like `$PATH`. This approach is standard for `bash`, but as far as I know, there is no reason to use it when ZSH provides better alternatives.

Comment: haha forget it, I though that was only a console command but adding that line to the .zshrc did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My .zshrc already had a line for export PATH so I replaced it with the modified one.

Comment: I had to remove the double quotes around the entries i.e. `PATH="/home/david/pear/bin:/usr/bin:etc"` to `PATH=/home/david/pear/bin:/usr/bin:etc` for it to stay in zshrc.

Comment: @taco, you can use $HOME

Comment: It will erase all the old PATH, try `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`

Comment: This appends to my existing PATH, and every time it's run, appends again. How do I set exactly what PATH should be?

Comment: You can set `PATH` directly: `export PATH=/some/where:/bin:/usr/bin` and so on. Is that what you're asking? The idea is to run the code in this answer in the `.zshrc` or `.profile` or something like that at the beginning of each session.

Comment: Just a side note, if your path has a space in it. then you need to wrap your path in double quotes like this:

```export PATH=$PATH:"/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

Answer (score 613):

Actually, using ZSH allows you to use special mapping of environment variables. So you can simply do:

```zsh
# append
path+=('/home/david/pear/bin')
# or prepend
path=('/home/david/pear/bin' $path)
# export to sub-processes (make it inherited by child processes)
export PATH
```

For me that's a very neat feature which can be propagated to other variables.
Example:

```
typeset -T LD_LIBRARY_PATH ld_library_path :
```

Comment: Nice answer. In my case, `~/.zshrc` is sourced after `.profile`, and overwrites everything in `.profile`. Took a while pulling my hair to figure it out.

Comment: The append case does does not need the parens unless you're appending more than one element. It also often doesn't need the quotes. So the simple, short way to append is

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, you should understand that almost any unix shell simply reads startup files which does almost the same as if you'd type it into shell interactively. Regarding "rc" files you might find interesting answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for)

Comment: It's possible to avoid explicit export with `-x` and leave only unique values in a variable with `-U`, colon is assumed by default, so it can be: `typeset -TUx PATH path`

Comment: I see the use of `path` and `PATH`, both are separate entities?

Comment: @CousinCocaine, you are right. ZSH variables are case-sensitive. `typeset -T` allows to tie `PATH` and `path` together in a special way that internally ZSH manages array variable `path` and reflects its contents in `PATH` as a scalar.

Comment: You can even have it as 1-liner: `export path=(... $path)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on my mac. I use the one liner answer below that updates ~/.zshrc insead.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen how can I see when these files are sourced? Is there a cmd?

Comment: @Timo, in case of zsh you can try something like `zsh -x -i -l -c true` to see all commands during shell start-up. That `-l` is to simulate login-like start (as it happens from text VT or over `ssh`). But you should understand that not always `zsh` will be started as login (e.g. graphical session) and some other parent process may somehow source `.profile` before spawning non-login `zsh` sub-process that inherits environment variables (including `PATH`) from parent process.

Comment: What if i want to use $HOME inside ' '?
path +=('$HOME/etc/etc')
doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Rotkiv, that's a bit different question about how single/double quotes are interpreted. I guess [zsh expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) covers this. Usually double-quotes allow string interpolation like `"$HOME/etc/etc"`, but single quotes makes it easier to represent text that should not get special treatment. Note that you can always mix in a single argument forms to have something like `"$HOME"'/etc/etc'` (double + single quotes) or `"$HOME"/etc/etc` (double quotes + unquoted).
P.S. Yes I'm lazy to try find link to good answer on SO :P

Comment: On macOS, you can prepend and append to your path variable as described in the post, adding to the .zshrc file. It works without exporting the PATH.

Comment: If this append or prepend syntax doesn't work for you, make sure that you are using lower case `path`. Lower case `path` is the array.

Comment: Thank you for showing the prepend as well! Didn't see it anywhere else.

Comment: This does not seem to work with `~`.

Comment: This didn't work for me even though things looked absolutely fine when I `echo $PATH`. I had to go back to the "traditional" syntax of something like: `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH`

Comment: @MinhNghĩa, `~` is expanded by shell. If you put it in quotes like `'~/bin'` or `"~/bin"` it will be literally tilda in your path. E.g. you can write `path+=(~/bin)` (note no quotes) or similar. If you need to quote something, you still can do it on part like `path+=(~/'some path with spaces')`.

Comment: @Phil, my best guess for your case is that ok result of `echo $PATH` shows your current shell value for it. Any chance it works if you do `export PATH` (upper case) to export for sub-process after setting `path` (lower case)?

Comment: Append did not work for me. Old school export did.

Comment: This might have worked in 2013, but it doesn't work in macOS in 2024.

Comment: I've been coming back to this answer since 2013. I mean... I could read the typeset man page to find args 'U' and 'x' but this has been working for over a decade and now I'm old and jaded. So thanks! and I'll see you guys next year.

Answer (score 116):

You can *append* to your `PATH` in a minimal fashion.  No need for
parentheses unless you're appending more than one element.  It also
usually doesn't need quotes.  So **the simple, short way to append** is:

```
path+=/some/new/bin/dir
```

This lower-case syntax is using `path` as an **array**, yet also
affects its upper-case partner equivalent, `PATH` (to which it is
"bound" via `typeset`).

*(Notice that **no `:` is needed/wanted as a separator**.)*

### Common interactive usage

Then the common pattern for testing a new script/executable becomes:

```
path+=$PWD/.
# or
path+=$PWD/bin
```

### Common config usage

You can sprinkle path settings around your `.zshrc` (as above) and it will naturally lead to the **earlier listed settings taking precedence** (though you may occasionally still want to use the "prepend" form `path=(/some/new/bin/dir $path)`).

### Related tidbits

Treating `path` this way (as an array) also means: **no need to do a
`rehash`** to get the newly pathed commands to be found.

Also take a look at **`vared path` as a dynamic way to edit `path`**
(and other things).

You may only be interested in `path` for this question, but since
we're talking about exports and arrays, note that
**[arrays generally cannot be exported.](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1997/msg00515.html)**

You can even **prevent `PATH` from taking on duplicate entries**
(refer to
[this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24)
and [this](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/1998/msg00490.html)):

```
typeset -U path
```

### PATH pre-populated

The reason your path already has some entries in it is due to your system shell files setting path for you. This is covered in a couple other posts:

- [Why and where the $PATH env variable is set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246751/how-to-know-why-and-where-the-path-env-variable-is-set)
- [Where is the source of $PATH? I cannot find it in .zshrc](https://superuser.com/questions/1464727/in-zsh-on-mac-os-where-is-the-source-of-path-i-cannot-find-it-in-zshrc)

Comment: @andrewlorien I updated the answer with details about the colon separator.

Comment: Note that if there’s a comment after the path, then we do need quotes, like `path+='my/path' # for fun`. It’s obvious if you have spaces, but not so much if you have comments.

Comment: "(Notice that no : is needed/wanted as a separator.)"

This is only true for a lowercase `path`. A preceding `:` is required for `PATH`, as follows in .zshrc

`PATH+=:/Users/path/to/my/folder`

Comment: I use a lot `exec zsh` because I work with plugins from `oh-my-zsh`.Everytime I do exec the path gets bigger. Should I "default" the path from time to time?

Comment: For ZSH to interpret $PATH as an array and make it unique, I believe the correct way would be `typeset -aU path`

Answer (score 75):

one liner, without opening `~/.zshrc` file

```
echo -n 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
echo -n 'export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc
```

To see the effect, do `source ~/.zshrc` in the same tab or open a new tab

Comment: Worked perfecly on OSX with Zsh shell.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Perfect! on MacOS M2

Comment: Thanks! One line solution seems perfect

Comment: Works in Catalina

Answer (score 39):

1. Added path to ~/.zshrc

   `sudo vi ~/.zshrc`

   add new path

   ```sh
   export PATH="$PATH:[NEW_DIRECTORY]/bin"
   ```
2. Update ~/.zshrc

   Save ~/.zshrc

   `source ~/.zshrc`
3. Check PATH

   `echo $PATH`

Comment: This is the `Bash` way.

Comment: effective way to do

Answer (score 26):

**OPTION 1:** Add this line to ~/.zshrc:

```
export "PATH=$HOME/pear/bin:$PATH"
```

After that you need to run `source ~/.zshrc` in order your changes to take affect OR close this window and open a new one

**OPTION 2:** execute it inside the terminal console to add this path only to the current terminal window session. When you close the window/session, it will be lost.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answer is different from [the same answer posted 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh/11530176#11530176)?

Comment: in this answer it is not said that you have to add this line of code to the file, if you just run it like that it will change only in the current windows and this is not explain in the original answer

Comment: add this to file .zshrc without qoutes export PATH=$HOME/pear/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 9):

If you are on macOS (I'm on Monterey 12.3.1), you may have been pulling your hair like I did metaphorically. These instructions above all worked for me within the terminal session, but I could never get it to persist no matter what I did with export. Moreover, I couldn't find the .zshrc anywhere.

Turns out Apple does it differently. The file you need to edit is `etc/paths`. You can simply `sudo nano /etc/paths` and add your path in a new line. Then simply restart terminal and voila.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've never known why `etc/paths` existed. It's much easier to use than all the export PATH stuff I've used in the past.

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me on Monterey. Thanks.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair for about 2 hours. I finally found the answer here. Thanks! This worked with Mac OS Monterey 12.5.1

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Monterey 12.4 and the *only* way I could change the path was using the helper function. Editing text files in nano did *diddly squat*

```zsh
# append
path+=('/foo/bar/yourpath')
# export to sub-processes 
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

for me `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/file/bin` 
then `export PATH` worked.
to  check `echo $PATH` . other solutions are adding the path temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new file to /etc/paths.d and you can add your path that file. Don't forget to restart your terminal.

```
**#create new file to /etc/paths.d**
  touch /etc/paths.d/[filename]
**#open created file and add your path**
  vi /etc/paths.d/[filename]
**#save and close file and restart terminal**
```

Answer (score 1):

A native zsh way is to identify your install directory and create a file from where you will load your `PATH` modifications:

```
touch $ZSH/custom/usrenv.zsh
```

And add the new PATH directories like this inside that `usrenv.zsh`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/myself/.foo/bin:/usr/local/bar/bin
```

The `custom` directory files `*.zsh` are sourced by default by the `.oh-my-zsh.sh` init script, as this snippet taken from it shows:

```
if [[ -z "$ZSH_CUSTOM" ]]; then
    ZSH_CUSTOM="$ZSH/custom"
fi
...
for config_file ("$ZSH_CUSTOM"/*.zsh(N)); do
  source "$config_file"
done
unset config_file
```

Answer (score 0):

to verify your new directory has been added correctly, you can use

`print -l $path`

thanks to the fact that its type is known to be an array

Comment: This answers a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

The lower case path variable didn't work for me. When I opened up my .zshrc there was already an `EXPORT PATH= "$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH", where $PATH is the current path variable set on the machine. All I did was append to the string adding a colon in front of the path. e.g.` export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:$HOME/go/bin"`

Anything after the `:` are the new paths to be appended.