# Recommended .zshrc settings for Android SDK

Tags: android, macos, path, zsh, environment

```html
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/baby/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
#PATH to my android

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/baby/ADT/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

# User configuration

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Why does my `$PATH` show this?

> zsh:no such file or
>   directory:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I use zsh and I have added this in `.zshrc`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/baby/ADT/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

How should my environment variables be set in zsh to use Android SDK in OSX EL Capitan?

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "why does my `$PATH` show this". `$PATH` is not even a command (or did you try to run it as a command? That would explain it, but it's still weird because the string shown in the error message doesn't seem to be your full path. Did you copy the full error message?)

Comment: ➜  ~  subl  .zshrc
➜  ~  .$PATH
zsh: no such file or directory: ./usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
➜  ~

Comment: i have use $PATH command,but it's like above.I want to know how to setting path when i use zsh in OSX EL Capitan

Comment: Don't post your messy prompt. Also, `.$PATH` is not a command.

Comment: echo $PATH show /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, but this seems right. i 'm more care .zshrc settings for Android SDK,when i type android command is not work on terminal

Comment: This is not right, it's the default PATH, unaffected by your zshrc.

Comment: Better post your full .zshrc, and .zlogin also, if you have one.

Comment: my full .zshrc as below answer, i'm confuse to .zsh to configure the environment

Comment: ok , i fix the post, can you give the solution to my problem

Comment: or give me some link to learn the .zsh environment configuration

Comment: As I said, your PATH customization is overwritten by `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` later in the file. You should put your own customizations at the end of the file.

Comment: As for learning, first, `man zsh`. Then, Zsh official documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/. If you're not the type who read reference manuals cover to cover, you should probably read http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_toc.html, which is a lightweight tutorial kind of thing, as far as I can tell (I don't really know the quality because I just read the reference manual). Or you could read the myriad tutorials for bash (e.g., http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), which mostly apply to zsh as well. And bash is simpler.

Comment: Oh, and there's this: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html, which seems more detailed than the intro.

Answer (score 12):

I have the following in my `.zshrc` file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
path=("${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools" $path)
```

The value of `ANDROID_HOME` will depend on your personal setup. I used [Homebrew - The missing package manager for OS X](http://brew.sh) to install the android-sdk:

```
brew install android-sdk
```

See also: [Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh/18077919#18077919)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I had to list in my `.zshrc`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I needed to add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` for legacy support in my project.