# Editing the ~/.zshrc file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh, zshrc

I'm a complete newbie, so I think I'm just missing a step, but have no idea.

I'm following tutorials for Rails. Lots of steps say, "`and then editing the ~/.zshrc file.`" but I don't have any ~/.zshrc file. I'm looking at the folders in Sublime. Also none of the following ~/.zprofile, ~/.zlogin, ~/.zlogout exist. Though, under my home files, there is .zprezto folder. No zshenv either...

Do I just create the files? Seems like they should be downloaded from somewhere. I'm using Terminal with OS X. So lost.

```
echo 'write whatever' >.zshrc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the sources of these tutorials?

Comment: Are you actually using `zsh`? You can check by opening a terminal and running the command `echo $0 $ZSH_VERSION`. If you are using `zsh` this should output something like "`/bin/zsh 5.0.2`". If it just says "`/bin/bash `" you are in fact using `bash`, the default shell in OS X, and adding anything to `~/.zshrc` will have no effect. Unless it uses commands, syntax or options that work only in zsh, you probably could add it to `~/.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 36):

You will get ~/.zshrc file only when you use zsh shell on your Mac OS. If you're not sure which shell you're using, open terminal and issue the following command.

```
echo $SHELL
```

if you get response like `/bin/zsh` then you're using zsh shell on your Mac. You can edit ~/.zshrc file using vim editor on your Mac which is the default for Mac OS.

to open ~/.zshrc file using vim editor, issue the following command on your terminal.

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Then you can do any configurations you need. Or else you can use `open -t .zshrc` command to open ~/.zshrc file from your general TextEdit on Mac OS.

Answer (score 31):

1. `$ open ~/.zshrc`
2. Make changes in the .zshrc file window that opens
3. Save file
4. `$ source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This is much easier.

Answer (score 4):

The `.zshrc` file is used to configure your terminal prompt if you're using zsh (z-shell) login shell (n.b., a "login shell" is the command line presented to you when running the terminal application). If you're using a standard OSX terminal, then you're probably using bash (the BASH Shell), so editing `.zshrc` wouldn't affect anything. Bash uses `.bashrc` and .bash_profile` for it's configuration. These file are run overtime you open terminal window and setup things the command aliases, setup your prompt and maybe run scripts to initial other programs.

You almost certainly don't need to edit terminal config files to develop with Ruby  on Rails, especially as editing these files incorrectly can mess up your system, or at least make it hard to return the system to a stable state.

Comment: Update: In 2019, Starting with macOS Catalina, Mac began using zsh as the default login shell and interactive shell. source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the vi(vim) editor to edit the .zshrc file.

1)To open ~/.zshrc

vi .zshrc 
or 
vi ~/.zshrc 
or 
You can open the file in VsCode, and it would be easier to edit it. 
code .zshrc

2)To update the edited .zshrc file:

source ~/.zshrc 
or 
source .zshrc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zsh shell , run the below lines in the terminal:

echo 'setopt PROMPT_CR' >.zshrc

echo 'setopt PROMPT_SP' >.zshrc

echo 'export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=""' >.zshrc

Answer (score 0):

You can edit **zshenv** instead of zshrc for appending **PATH** . Please check whether file already exists

> cat ~/.zshevn

You can edit file using below command

> vi ~/.zshenv

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh) to see how to add an entry in PATH