# MEAN environment setup: Stuck on zsh: command not found, Big Sur

Tags: node.js, angular, bash, macos, zsh

I am setting for MEAN stack on Mac Big Sur (M1) and I am unable to install packages due to zsh: command not found.

Here is what I have done so far.
installed nvm (curl code from GitHub), `nvm install node`, `~/.nvm/nvm.sh`.  Tested with `-v nvm` and `node -v`, confirmed to be working.
`echo $0 $ZSH_VERSION` shows `-zsh 5.8`
`npm install -g @angular/cli` got `zsh: command not found: npm`.
Followed [Command not found after npm install in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743928/command-not-found-after-npm-install-in-zsh) which recommended to add `source /home/YOUUSERNAME/.bash_profile` at the beginning of `~/.zshrc` file.

To edit ~/.zshrc followed [Editing the ~/.zshrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157663/editing-the-zshrc-file)
Did `vim ~/.zshrc`, in the first line of ~/.zshrc file, added `source /home/Dickson_Local_AC/.bash_profile`.
Did ctrl + X  to save, bottom of page showed `-- INSERT --`, closing terminal only gives terminate or cancel, chose terminate. The changes did not save, opening the file only shows `~/.zshrc" [New]` at the bottom line.

Now `npm`, `node -v` show `zsh: command not found`. Reinstalled `nvm`, same problem.

What am I doing wrong? Can you lead me out of the stalemate and advice on how to install MEAN packages?

Comment: Don't just source `.bash_profile` from `.zshrc`; the two shells are not mutually compatible. You'll have to add the relevant parts of `.bash_profile` to `.zprofile`, adjusting the code as necessary to create valid `zsh` code.

Comment: Also, on Mac, I think your user home directories are normally under `/Users`, not `/home`, so if you did want to source your `.bash_profile` (and it's not clear to me why that would help) then it would be better to use `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Note also that despite being a big fan of `vim`, I would be the first to admit that it is ... quirky.  If it's available then you will find the GUI version (`gvim`) somewhat easier to use, but I would instead recommend the standard Mac `TextEdit` to most Mac users who don't already have a preferred editor.

Comment: Thanks @chepner and @John Bollinger . I am very new to this and still trying to understand ```zsh``` and profile. What do I need to do to go past the zsh: command not found and be able to install say Angular

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` contains an assignment to `PATH` that adds the directory where `nvm` installs things. In `.zprofile`, you can add a line like `path+=( ... )`, where `...` is the appropriate directory. (I don't use Node, but I recall it's something like `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: @chepner I have bash and zsh files here ```Dickson_Local_AC@Air-Muoki /bin``` typed in```path+=Dickson_Local_AC@Air-Muoki /bin``` on the terminal. Result ```zsh: permission denied: /bin```