# How do I update PHP version without homebrew and using ZSH?

Tags: php, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to update my PHP version from 7.1.x to 7.3.x. Unfortunately once I run the curl command to update the version, my `php -v` still outputs the following.

```
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2018 16:59:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Heres the curl command I'm using and the reference of where I found this command.

`curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3`

Reference: https://php-osx.liip.ch/

I've then added the following to my `.zshrc` file to update my path with ZSH's built in mapping. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/6572260

```
# Append to Path PHP
path+=("/usr/local/php5/bin")

# Export the PATH
export PATH=$PATH
```

This doesn't work either and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So after **much** headbanging on my desk, I finally figured it out.  5 hours later.

I tried many methods, but what I didn't realize was that the **path for php has to be prepended and not appended to the path**.

So the line in my `.zshrc` file needed to be changed from

```
# Append to Path PHP
path+=("/usr/local/php5/bin")
```

```
# Prepend the Path for PHP
path=("/usr/local/php5/bin" $path)
```

Also a little note, that the `$path` can also be `$PATH` inside the mapping.

Hopefully this helps someone along the way who was running into the same issue and hitting a giant wall.

Reference first Question in F.A.Q. section here: https://php-osx.liip.ch/#faq