# PATH gets "reset"/wiped after manually adding a value (zsh)

Tags: zsh

I recently updated to macOS Catalina, and it uses zsh.  I had a few custom installations (node, aws-cli, docker) and after the installations I was able to invoke them though iTerm and the other terminals.  I was trying to install maven, and had to manually update the PATH. In .zprofile I found this:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/libexec
```

And added the new maven location to the end.  This worked in helping me invoke maven from the terminal, however the rest of my installs (the ones I didn't had to manually update the path for) where gone.  I immediately reverted the file to its previous state, but have no luck.  Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: [Perhaps this question and its answers would help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I saw it :) however my confusion is due to how before I was able to use the rest of my executables just fine, and now everything is messed up, even after I rolled-back.

Comment: I wish I could help you out but I don't use MacOS or Linux or zsh.