# Add flutter to environment path (Bash)

Tags: bash, flutter, environment-variables

I am trying to permanently add flutter to my PATH. I will tell you what I previously did. So I unzipped the MacOS version in my user folder. Then I went into my .bash-profile and added export PATH:/Users/kayajones/flutter/bin:$PATH. Saved that quit out of the terminal completely and when I type flutter I get the "env: bash: No such file or directory". I also tried deleting flutter and reinstalling and doing the steps over again. Still no luck, I've been stuck on this all day. The setup process is a pain. Sorry in advance i dont have a high enough reputation to be adding in images.
[bash error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsKyy.jpg)

Comment: That line should be `export PATH="/Users/kayajones/flutter/bin:$PATH"` -- note the equal sign and double-quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh)

Comment: @omajid I already have that in my .bash-profile I also added in double-quotes and quitted terminal. now when I open back up the terminal some of my commands aren't working for example ls and vim. Also when I type in: source .bash-profile it says that there is no file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, make sure you got the path right.
2. Then try adding `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kayajones/flutter/bin"` to your .bash-profile file.
3. Then exit the terminal and restart it.
4. Then run `source .bash-profile`

Comment: now when i try to run any command like or example ls or vim it is saying that the command is not found. When i tried to run: source .bash-profile it says no such file or directory. @Buckyball

Comment: The command source is used to run bash config files

Comment: It once happened with me too. This usually happens due to one of the lines .bash-profile. Now, you have to edit .bash-profile manually using a text editor and find out the error blocking resource

Comment: I have updated the answer, try it, if it doesn't work then try removing the '/' before 'Users'

Comment: ok, when I open up _bash.profile in my vscode no text is in there. Is that where i add the export code. or is _bash.profile different from .bash-profile? @Buckyball

Comment: @KayaJones .bash_profile is the original file, use that **only**

Comment: I can't even open anything up or look for the .bash-profile from my terminal. it says vim command not found

Comment: How do i get to .bash_profile the only thing i see to edit in my text editor is _bash.profile

Comment: Try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107104)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
cd $home

nano ~/.bash_profile

export PATH="$HOME/Documents/_____/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

Instead of:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Users/ Name /Documents/_____/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow image arrow works inn macOS BigSur