# Windows subsystem for Linux - cannot find npm after zsh/oh-my-zsh install

Tags: bash, npm, terminal, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed zsh and oh-my-zsh on WSL following [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/). They both work fine but it seems that my previous installs don't work, such as `npm`.

Does anything else need to be done?

Comment: Maybe it's dont read your `$PATH` that include npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh#11530176)

add this line to .zshrc:
`export PATH=$PATH` (add path of npm if not already in $PATH.)
`source ~/.zshrc`

or do one of these:
`echo -n 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`

`echo -n 'export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`