# .zshrc: command not found: jenv

Tags: command-line, terminal, jenv

I recently followed the steps to install jENV and Corretto-8. Unfortunately now whenever I open a new terminal I see the following:

```
Last login: XXXXXXX
/Users/username/.zshrc: command not found: jenv
/Users/username/.zshrc: command not found: jenv
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am truly at a loss.

Comment: presumably, the jENV  & Corr install created some of their own directories, or there is a log file that you could search? Try running `find /some/dir/for/jENV -name jENV -ls`? or `find $HOME ...` or `find /usr/local ...` ? Figure out where the file was created, and then change the configuration of jENV & Corr. to include that path in its setup information. Look for errors in the install log. Running out of ideas. Good luck.

Comment: fwiw I did `brew install jenv` and `brew uninstall jenv` and the error stopped showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed it using MacOS brew and did this as well:

> $ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> $ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Now, you will have a duplicate command in your bash. Remove those two lines in your bash and you should be good.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is likely occurring because jenv has not been added to your PATH before `jenv init` runs. Look at your .zshrc file and ensure the jenv section looks like this

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

Also, be sure that you don't have multiple jenv sections since the [installation instructions](https://www.jenv.be/) for Zsh are not re-runnable. If you accidentally ran the instructions for Zsh twice, you will find two jenv sections at the end of your .zshrc file and you should delete one of them.

Comment: It was helpful. Also, to update and correct the path in  ~/.zshrc I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh

Answer (score 0):

Today I was running into the same problem. I installed `jenv` via `brew` but it showed every time: "command not found".

The solution was, that `jenv` wasn't linked. So I run the following command and everything worked after that:

```bash
brew link jenv
```