# zsh: command not found: brew in mac

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh, psql

I had homebrew installed on my mac. Today after sometime, I tried to download psql through brew on my mac on terminal but I keeping getting:

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

I have it installed so I do not know why zsh is not picking brew?

Comment: You probably need to add the directory where `brew` is located to your path.  Try adding `path+=(/usr/local/bin)` to the `.zshrc` file in your home directory and restarting the terminal session. More about paths here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh and here: https://andysbrainbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unix/Unix_04_ShellsVariables.html

Answer (score 2):

First you have run the below command for install homebrew on particular path

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And then set the path using below command

```
echo export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Its working fine for MacOS

Comment: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc` does not add the line starting with `export PATH` to `~/.zshrc`. It only adds the _stdout_ from running that command to `~/.zshrc`, and the command has no stdout at all.

Comment: Maybe you want to suggest `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.zshrc` instead?