# How can I stop invalid value 'ada' in '-x ada' error?

Tags: ada

I know this has been answered before, but nothing I have seen has worked!!!
I'm not panicking just slightly mad it's not working.
It has never worked once.
I tried:

adding gnat to the path again,

gcc -c -x ada hello.adb

Comment: Try `gcc -c -x ada hello.adb`.

Comment: @trashgod same error

Comment: I get `error: invalid value 'ada' in '-x ada'` only when I remove GNAT from the path.

Comment: @trashgod look at the i tried part

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` to verify the `PATH` in the current shell.

Comment: @trashgod /usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/Users/blessb/.rbenv/shims:/Users/blessb/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/blessb/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin:/Applications/commands:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin

Comment: :/Users/blessb/.cargo/bin

Comment: Try `which gcc` to see if another one is preempting `GNAT.

Comment: @trashgod /usr/bin/gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looks like `/usr/bin` appears in your `$PATH` *before* the desired path, `/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin`. The search for `gcc` finds the original, which appears to be unaware of Ada. One solution is to add the GNAT directory to the *front* of your `PATH`, so that it will take precedence.

```
export PATH=/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin:$PATH
```

As @Simon Wright [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755729/how-can-i-stop-invalid-value-ada-in-x-ada-error/66756194?noredirect=1#comment118016491_66756194), see [*Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530090/230513) for additional details regarding path management.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: uh...... /usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/Users/blessb/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/blessb/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin:/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin: my path!
:( gnatmake: error, unable to locate gcc

Comment: it did not work. in fact, it stopped GCC from even being found!

Comment: The exact formulation will depend your shell and where it stores your profile, e.g. `bash` and `~/.bash_profile`. You may need to check your GNAT installation, too.

Comment: I use zsh as it is the default shell on macos catalina

Comment: I don't use zsh; try invoking `/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin/gcc -c -x ada …` directly.

Comment: now the question is how to fix:
gnatbind -x hello.ali
gnatlink hello.ali
clang: error: unknown argument: '-gnatA'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-gnatWb'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-gnatiw'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-gnatws'
gnatmake: *** link failed.

Comment: I found [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh) quite confusing (as a long-term bash user, I might have snarked about zsh vs bash, but bash PATH settings and shell startup configuration are a black art too). Anyway, you could try `PATH=/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin:$PATH` or (zsh only) `path=(/Users/blessb/opt/GNAT/2020/bin $path)`. Fairly soon, you’re going to want to put something like that in one of your zsh startup files (perhaps `~/.zshrc`?)

Comment: now it works! thanks! imma keep this question in case someone needs help