# VisualStudioCode (with LatexWorkshop) gives spawn latexmk ENOENT, but latex is in the path. (MacOs)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, path, vscode-extensions, latexmk

I'm unable to use LatexWorkshop+VSCode as I'm getting the known error `LaTeX fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT, . PID: undefined.`.
I'm using a fresh install of TexLive (through MacTex on MacOs).
Yet, although `/Library/Tex/texbin` is in my path (here is the output from echo $PATH):

```
/Users/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin:/Users/myusername/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/myusername/.fig/bin.
```

Here are some other relevant system info.

```
> which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
> which tlmgr
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr
> which latexmk
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk
```

So, it seems that latex is in my path, but when I try to compile I inevitably get the following error:

```
LaTeX build process spawned. PID: undefined.
LaTeX fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT, . PID: undefined.
Does the executable exist? $PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
Does the executable exist? $Path: undefined
The environment variable $SHELL: /bin/zsh
```

I even tried to force in LatexWorkshop settings by using the following in latexmk"env": `{ "TEXMFHOME": "/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk" }`

I already restarted VSCode several times (as well as the OS), and tried other solutions (e.g. [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179318/recipe-terminated-with-fatal-error-spawn-latexmk-enoenthttps://)) but I just can't make this work.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two methods you can try.

1. Use terminal `code` to launch a VS Code, rather than Finder. See: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1414
2. Use `"PATH"` rather than `"TEXMFHOME"` in `env`, see: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1742. I don't know what `"TEXMFHOME"` means although it is an example in the [LaTeX Workshop wiki](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#:%7E:text=%22TEXMFHOME%22%3A%20%22%25DIR%25/texmf%22).

Both methods are tried by myself and succeed.