# Unable to run NestJS CLI command. zsh: command not found: nest

Tags: javascript, nestjs

After what seems like a successful global installation of the NestJS CLI by running `npm i -g @nestjs/cli`, I am unable to get zsh to recognize the `nest` command. It always throws `zsh: command not found: nest`. I am working on a Macbook Pro with Big Sur v 11.6 and node v14.17.6. Any ideas at all as to why I am unable to get the command working would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your terminal? What's your `$PATH`` variable? Does it include the install location for npm global packages?

Comment: I have made sure to restart my terminal. When I run `echo PATH` this is what is spit out: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

Comment: Looks like globally installed npm packages aren't in your path. [You can read through this SO post and answer for more info on the install path and how you can get it into your $PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: Running `npm root -g` gives me `/Users/daviddelgadillo/.npm-global/lib/node_modules`. Is this what I need to add to my $PATH?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it the following way:

1. I entered `npm list -g` in my terminal to check where global packages are installed.
   In my case it was `/Users/aleksey.malakhov/.npm-global/lib`.
2. `.npm-global` contains `bin` and `lib` folders.
   We need `/Users/aleksey.malakhov/.npm-global/bin` to be exposed to `zsh`.
3. I added `path+=/Users/aleksey.malakhov/.npm-global/bin` in my `.zshrc` file, restarted terminal checked `nest -v` and it worked.
   [This topic helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh)