# How to colour git branch name in zsh prompt

Tags: git, colors, zsh, prompt

I have the following set in my `.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook vcs_info
setopt prompt_subst
add-zsh-hook precmd vcs_info

zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
```

and this in my
custom zsh theme :

```
vcs_info_wrapper() {
  vcs_info
  if [[ "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "master" ]]; then
    echo "%{$FG[196]%}"
  else
    echo "%{$fg[cyan]%}"
  fi
}
```

`PROMPT=$'%B%{$FG[039]%}%n%b%{$fg_bold[white]%}@%m%{$FG[220]%} %{\x1b[3m%}%5~ %{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}%{\x1b[0m%} %(?.%{$fg[white]%}.%{$fg_bold[red]%}[%?])» %{$FG[010]%}  ||$(vcs_info_wrapper)${vcs_info_msg_0_}|| '`

I have both `$(vcs_info_wrapper)${vcs_info_msg_0_}` and `$(git_prompt_info)` to test the colour output. For some reason the former always works and has the correct colour, but the latter doesn't and once the colour changes it never resets. I've basically tried everything at this point. Any ideas are welcome

EDIT:

Thanks @Gairfowl to I have most of it working now with:

```
function my_precmd {
  vcs_info
  local user='%B%F{#00ACE6}%n%f%b'

  local host='%B%F{white}@%m%f%b'
  local path='%F{#FFD700}%4~%f'
  local rcAndArrow='%(?.%F{white}.%B%F{red}[%?])»%f%b'

  local git2color='cyan'
  local git2=""

  [[ "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "master" || "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "main" ]] && git2color='196'

  if [[  "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" != "" ]]
    then
      local git2="%B%F{${git2color}}($(git_prompt_info))%f%b "
  fi

  psvar[1]="${user}${host} ${path} ${git2}${rcAndArrow} "
```

However I don't get any git information from `$(git_prompt_info)` If I combine it with `path` (like this `local path="%F{#FFD700}%4~%f $(git_prompt_info)"`) that seems to work.

Comment: I doubt this will fix your problem, but using `%F` and `%f` is simpler and cleaner than embedding terminal-specific escape sequences that need to be wrapped in `%{...%}`.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail. I'm mostly using `%F` and only using escape sequences for bolding the prompt. If there's somewhere I can improve on it I'll gladly try it out

Comment: You don't appear to be using `%F` at all. You're using, for example, `$FG[039]`, which I assume contains some sort of ANSI escape sequence.

Comment: ahh thanks for pointing that out. will work on that

Comment: There's a bit more on `%F` and `$fg` here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580488/432774 and in the 'Expansion of prompt sequences' / 'visual effects' section of the `zshmisc` man page.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often much easier to read and debug a `precmd` function than to
put everything in the `PROMPT` variable. Try building your prompt like the function below; you can comment out pieces and isolate the parts you're working on:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook vcs_info
setopt prompt_subst
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd

zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'

function my_precmd {
  local theUser='%B%F{39}%n%f%b'
  local theHost='%B%F{white}@%m%f%b'
  local git1="%F{220}~%f$(git_prompt_info)"
  local rcAndArrow='%(?.%F{white}.%B%F{red}[%?])»%f%b'

  vcs_info
  local git2color='cyan'
  [[ "${vcs_info_msg_0_}" == "master" ]] && git2color='196'
  local git2="||%F{${git2color}}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%f||"

  psvar[1]="${theUser}${theHost} ${git1} ${rcAndArrow} "
  psvar[2]="${git2}"
}

PROMPT='${psvar[1]}'
RPROMPT='${psvar[2]}'
```

Comment: I'll try that out. Should this be in the `.zshrc` or in my theme file? (I assume the `.zshrc because of the autoload but wanna make sure) 

On that note is it better practice to have it in the `.zshrc` directly?

Comment: Start with everything in `~/.zshrc` - it'll be easier to debug. Theme files are useful if you frequently switch between multiple prompts and such, but IMO they're usually more effort to manage than they are worth.

Comment: that was definitely helpful. I almost have it working. I noticed that
`local git1="%F{#FFD700}%4~%f $(git_prompt_info)"` works when added to my prompt but separating it out like this :
`local path='%F{#FFD700}%4~%f'` and `local git1="$(git_prompt_info)"` `psvar[1]="${user}${host} ${path} ${git1} ${rcAndArrow} "` 
doesn't. It leaves off any git info. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: `path` is a reserved variable in `zsh` - it's the array version of the `PATH` scalar variable.  It's part of neat zsh-ism where variables can be 'tied' together with `typeset -T` (there's a [bit more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/9307265)). Your assignment is causing problems for the `get_prompt_info` code; use a different name (e.g. `thePath`) and it should be ok. (Also, I should have avoided `user` and `host` - I updated the answer).

Comment: Yupp that was it. Amazing help! Thanks