# zsh escape white space in the "for file in path" syntax

Tags: escaping, zsh

I want to loop through files in "/test/my project/abc/*" using zsh script on Mac OSX.

```
path="/test/my project/abc/*"
for file in ${path}; do
    something
done
```

will result in white space not being escaped and error occuring.

I also tried

```
path="/test/my project/abc/*"
for file in "${path}"; do
    something
done
```

In most other usage this method of escaping would have worked but in the "for ... in ..." case it instead treat the whole "${path}" as a string array and only list the single string.

I am stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `path='/test/my project/abc'; for file in $path/*; do ...; done` would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File globbing with a variable expansion is turned off by default in `zsh`.  You have to explicitly request it with `${~...}`:

```
ls 'sub dir'; print

p="sub dir/*"
for f in ${~p}; do
    print "in loop: [$f]"
done
```

output:

```
fl1     fl2     fl3

in loop: [sub dir/fl1]
in loop: [sub dir/fl2]
in loop: [sub dir/fl3]
```

Note that this does not use `path` as a variable name. `path` is usually tied to the `PATH` variable, and is effectively a reserved word in zsh. That may be why you saw different results with your examples; in a default zsh configuration, both the quoted and unquoted forms should simply return the pattern and not the glob results.

More info:

- `zshexpn` - this man page has a description of `${~spec}`.
- `GLOB_SUBST` is described in `zshoptions`. This is another way to force globbing with a variable expansion , but it's usually not a good idea to set this option.
- Some notes about `path`, `PATH`, and `typeset -T`:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/9307265

Comment: I had an error saying "${~assetFiles}: bad substitution". My code has the following four lines by trying the method you described: `projectPath="/Users/adminadmin/Tutorials/New Unity Project"` `assetBundlePath="${projectPath}/AssetBundles/OSX"` `assetFiles="${assetBundlePath}/*"` `for file in ${~assetFiles}; do` using your syntax and the error occured at the last line containing `for`.

Comment: @cr001 - it sounds like your shell is `bash`, not `zsh`. macOS will sometimes display a message about the default shell now being `zsh`, but it doesn't actually change the shell for an existing account.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe it's because I am using Jenkins to run the script on Mac. I know it becomes kind of off-topic but is there a good way to achieve my purpose using bash then? I will accept your answer as it answered my original question.

Comment: One thing to try is what @chepner mentioned above, moving the wildcard into the loop: `for file in "${assetBundlePath}"/*`. Or if you can add a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the script, that can eliminate some of the dependency on the calling environment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do **NOT** name your own variable `path`. This name is a special meaning in zsh, and you may observe all kinds of funny effects if you fiddle with this variable in a different way as was forseen by the zsh designers.

Secondly, since your variable - let's call it `pathes` - is supposed to represent a set of pathes, it would make more sense to use an array:

```
pathes=(/test/my project/abc/*)
for file in $pathes[@]
do
  something
done
```