# How to declare command path globally in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, command

While processing with Mac terminal, sometimes I got a message like 'something is not command'.

I think there's a way to declare path globally where I am. (Such as 'brew')

I want to add path in the list that when I 'echo $PATH'

'export Path=~/path/bin:$PATH' is defined and evaporated when I exit the terminal.

Share your knowledge to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right command: `export PATH=/your/custom/folder:$PATH`
What you're missing is to add this somewhere.
If you're using bash as a shell this might be `~/.bashrc`, if it's zsh something like `~/.zshrc` and just append your export line to the end of the file. You can check what shell you're using with `echo $SHELL`.

Changes are reflected the next time you open a terminal, or just run `source ~/.zshrc` to update the current session.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh this also helps