# What is the right file where add search paths to the zsh enviroment variable `PATH` on macOS

Tags: macos, zsh

I just compiled **Ruby** from source and it is located into `/usr/local/ruby`

In order to access Ruby's executables I edited `~/.zshenv` adding `/usr/local/ruby/bin` to the `export PATH` directive:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However restarting the terminal and running `which ruby` still returns macOS's default `/usr/bin/ruby`

In fact inspecting `PATH` reveals:

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
```

So **after** my `~/.zshenv` is excecuted another configuration file prepends `/usr/bin` to `PATH`.

Where does this happen?

I would expect to find `/usr/bin` already in `PATH` when `.zshenv` is processed (resulting in having this path at the end of the environment variable).

What I am missing?

---

I checked and there are no other **zsh** configuration files in my home directory, just `.zshenv`;

I checked `/etc` too and found

```
zprofile
zshrc
zshrc_Apple_Terminal
```

but none of those do alter the `PATH` variable

---

on `/etc/paths`

I have

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

but again, shouldn't be `PATH` already set with those paths when `.zshenv` is processed ?

Comment: In `~/.zshenv`, put `set -x` just after `export PATH`, you may be able to see where PATH is prepended.

Comment: Did you only check for `PATH`, or also for `path`?  Those two variables are synchronized. Did you check the startup files in `/etc`? Another possibility is that your startup files are **sourcing** other files, and the PATH is reset there.  Try to create a subshell with `zsh -lx` and analyze the output.

Comment: @user1934428 well, a lot of stuff came out from `zsh -lz`. I ended removing both `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshenv`. Then I edited `/etc/paths` and added there the search paths in the desired order

Comment: Well, if you have a lot of setup to do, you get a lot of output.  Assuming that you *need*  all this for configuring your zsh properly, I suggest you redirect the output to a file and analyte it with i.e. a text editor. If you don't need it, of course it is better to remove those unneeded files.

Answer (score 0):

The right place to alter `PATH` by appending user's search directories is `~/.zshrc` that is sourced last.

This solution is based on the answers and comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530090/1579327), other answers and comments to my question.

---

<s>Following @[Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125671/philippe) advice I noticed actually `.zshenv` is sourced first, before any other configuration file/script.</s>

<s>After reading a [post on the Zsh Mailing List Archive](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2003/msg00600.html) I put my `PATH` setting directives into `~/.zpath`</s>

<s>Then `~/.zpath` has to be sourced from `~/.zshenv` when not in a login shell:</s>

<s>`if [[ $SHLVL == 1 && ! -o LOGIN ]]; then`</s>

<s>`source ~/.zpath`</s>

<s>`fi`</s>

<s>And from `~/.zprofile` that is executed only when in a login shell.</s>

<s>`source ~/.zpath`</s>

---

<s>Alternatively **o̲n̲ ̲m̲a̲c̲O̲S̲** it possible to just edit directly `/etc/paths`</s>

<s>`/usr/local/mysql/bin`</s>

<s>`/usr/local/ruby/bin`</s>

<s>`/usr/local/bin`</s>
<s>`/usr/local/sbin`</s>

<s>`/usr/bin`</s>

<s>`/bin`</s>

<s>`/usr/sbin`</s>

<s>`/sbin`</s>

Comment: What files are processed in which order depends on your configuration as well. The order of the configuration files sourced on startup is documented in _man zsh_, section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_. Note that .zpath is **not** processed by default, so using this file is a dangerous adivce.

Comment: Also, be careful: Using `/etc/paths` works specifically on MacOS, but not in genreal for zsh. While you have properly tagged your question _macos_, it does not harm to explicitly point out in your answer that this is not a suggestions for zsh in the general case, but specific to the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust apple to leave your /etc/paths directory alone, it's in their scope. Unless you have a need to manage this on a multiple person level, I would stick to changes in ~. For quick impact, I just add exports to .zshrc, and this is where I have my rvm bin directory added to my path.