# MacOS path is a space delimited version of PATH and they are linked in zsh

Tags: bash, macos, path, zsh

In most shells, `$VAR` and `$var` and `$Var` are three different variables because the shell (all that >> I << am aware of) is case sensitive.

In `zsh` on MacOS 13.01:

```
[Start a fresh copy of zsh]

% s=tst
% S="something else"
% echo "\$s=$s"
$s=tst
% echo "\$S=$S"    
$S=something else
% [[ "$s" == "$S" ]] || echo "Not equal"
Not equal
```

However, in `zsh` on MacOS, examine `$PATH` and `$path`:

```
% echo $PATH
/Users/dawg/perl5/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

% echo $path
/Users/dawg/perl5/bin /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

It appears that `$path` is a space delimited version of `$PATH`.

Now change `PATH` in the typical way:

```
% export PATH=/some/new/folder:$PATH
% echo $PATH
/some/new/folder:/Users/dawg/perl5/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

That is what I expect, but it also changes `$path`:

```
% echo $path
/some/new/folder /Users/dawg/perl5/bin /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

**WORSE**, changing `$path` also changes `$PATH`!

This is not the same in a `brew` install of Bash which has no secret `$path` waiting to bite.

It bit me (with an hour of head scratching) with a loop like this on zsh on MacOS:

```
for path in **/*.txt; do
    # do some things with sys utilities with $path...
    # sys utilities like awk in the PATH were not found
done
```

---

Questions:

1. Is the `$PATH` / `$path` link documented somewhere?
2. What is the purpose?
3. How do I turn this off??
4. Why would Apple do this???

Comment: Regarding 4, this has nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: There's no reason to expect `bash` and `zsh` to behave the same; they are two different shells.

Comment: (1) yes of course, in the zsh documentation (3) why would you want to? It’s a *feature*. (4) as noted, nothing to do with Apple.

Comment: I can imagine wanting to turn it off, at least on a case-by-case basis. The general advice in `bash` (and POSIX shells in general) is to avoid all-uppercase names as reserved. This feature causes some all-lowercase names to be effectively reserved as well.

Comment: The POSIX specification words it as " The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.", implying that anything *not* containing a lowercase letter (including mixed-case names) *might* be used elsewhere.

Comment: `zsh` itself is not a POSIX-compliant *shell* (though it can be treated as one by setting the correct options), but it is typically used in POSIX-compliant systems, so things like naming conventions are still applicable. Using `path` in the manner is *technically* compliant; `zsh` is an application and can do what it likes with the "reserved" name `path`. (It is a bit of a gotcha, though, if you aren't expecting or aware of this use.)

Comment: @chepner … I just realised that I completely misread your initial comment. After rereading it I now fully agree with you. And yes, the fact that non-uppercase names are reserved in zsh can certainly be seen as unfortunate.

Comment: POSIX states that all utilities covered by the specification use environment variables consisting of uppercase, underscores, and digits. If you want to avoid one of those utilities from stepping on your own variables, you need to ensure at least one lowercase letter is in the name. So "reserved" is probably not the most *technical* way to do describe this, but the *safest* approach is to avoid such names.

Comment: The array `path` is documented in _man zshparam_, in the section _PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL_. You can't turn off this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`path` is an array that is "tied" to `PATH`. This is a general feature provided by `zsh` via the `typeset -T` command.

```
$ typeset -T FOO foo '+'
$ FOO=a+b+c
$ print -l $FOO
a+b+c
$ print -l $foo
a
b
c
```

Here, `FOO` is the scalar and `foo` is the array. (Pairs of names that are identical except for case is a convention, not a requirement).
`+` is the separator between elements in the scalar that determines the values of the corresponding array. Modifying one variable affects the other.

The purpose is to make it easier to modify `PATH`, by adding or removing directories to the array and letting the shell handle updating the scalar with necessary separators.

`path` and `PATH` behave as if defined with

```
typeset -T PATH path :
```

or

```
typeset -T PATH path
```

(`:` is the default separator, as the feature is intended to provide array equivalent of variables like `PATH`, `MANPATH`, etc.)

There is no way to "untie" such scalar/array pairs; I would just accept that `path` is effectively reserved by `zsh`.

> Both  the scalar and the array may be manipulated as normal.  If one is unset, the other  will  automatically  be
> unset  too.   There  is  no  way of untying the variables
> without unsetting them, nor of converting the type of one
> of  them  with another typeset command; +T does not work,
> assigning an array to scalar is an error, and assigning a
> scalar to array sets it to be a single-element array.

You can see what other pairs are defined using `typeset -T` and no other arguments. It will list all variables in lexicographic order (which means all uppercase names, likely scalars, followed by all lowercase names, likely arrays).

Comment: As to 'the purpose' it is so you can do `path+=/some/new/path` in zsh as seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/298607) Your answer allowed me to find this but could not before. Thanks!