# How can I permanently add a path to a path-related environment variable, when it may or may not be empty?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to permanently add a path to $PYTHONPATH.  According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3402176/1299362), adding

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

to the `.bashrc` file should accomplish this on a Mac or GNU/Linux distro.  However, on my system, `$PYTHONPATH` is empty, so after doing the export, if I `echo $PYTHONPATH`, it returns `:/my/other/path` -
which is not a valid path because of the prefixed `:`. One way around this is to do

```
export PYTHONPATH="/my/other/path"
```

but that would clobber other paths if they do exist on different machines. How can I handle both cases?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: This is also addressed in some answers there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: Please tag questions according to the problem you are trying to solve, not according to why you want to solve it. A Python expert has no particular advantage in explaining how to set environment variables in a particular shell; an expert in that shell does.

Comment: Thanks, someone has added bash, and I have added zsh as it works for zsh as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if -z` test will tell you if the variable is empty/unset.  If so, don't use a colon, otherwise do use one.

```
if [ -z ${PYTHONPATH} ];
then
    export PYTHONPATH="/my/other/path"
else
    export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/other/path
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH#:}
```

This would remove an initial colon resulting from an initially empty `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh` you can use `typeset -T` to create 'tied' variables that are ideal for manipulating paths. These variables can be set to only add colons as needed, to only add unique elements to the path, and to export the result.

```bash
typeset -xUT PYTHONPATH pythonpath 

pythonpath+=/usr/local/lib
print $PYTHONPATH
# ==> /usr/local/lib

pythonpath+=/usr/lib
pythonpath+=/usr/local/lib # duplicate not added
print $PYTHONPATH
# ==> /usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077919/9307265).

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
[ -z "${PYTHONPATH-}" ] && export PYTHONPATH="/my/other/path" || export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

which is the same as the previous answer.