# How to debug in Android Studio using adb over WiFi

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

I'm able to connect to my phone using adb connect, and I can adb shell also.

But when I go to Run->Device Chooser, there are no devices there.

What should I do to connect my (connected) adb Android Studio?

When I plug it in through USB, it shows up on the list

Comment: What is listed when you do adb devices in the console?

Comment: 192.168.2.4:5555              device

Comment: It works with Android studio 1.5 RC here, so not sure whats wrong. Only thing that I could suggest it try to it once more with setting up. 1) adb kill-server   2) Then do the steps to connect again.. If not it also exist a plugin which I have not tried that might help https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB/issues

Comment: @John is this device have some specific usb driver?If yes then, just try to re-install driver and kill adb may be it will help you!

Comment: please Read this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi#) Described Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run/install/debug Android applications over Wi-Fi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893953/run-install-debug-android-applications-over-wi-fi)

Answer (score 138):

You can find the adb tool in /platform-tools/

```
cd Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

You can check your devices using:

```
./adb devices
```

My result:

```
List of devices attached
XXXXXXXXX   device
```

Set a TCP port:

```
./adb shell setprop service.adb.tcp.port 4444

./adb tcpip 4444
```

Result message:

```
restarting in TCP mode port: 4444
```

To init a wifi connection you have to check your device IP and execute:

```
./adb connect 192.168.0.155:4444
```

Comment: *I'm able to connect to my phone using adb connect, and I can adb shell also.* I got this far. Android Studio just doesn't pick it up

Comment: Adb connection Error:EOF

Comment: +1, got it working, thanks!  But wow, now I know I'll go back to the cable.  Debugging (from Visual Studio) over WiFi was abominably slow to deploy, slow to run, and slow to shut down.  :)

Comment: @john try connecting to your android device using adb ip:port and you'll see it on android studio device picker

Comment: unable to connect to 192.168.3.110:4444: cannot connect to 192.168.3.110:4444: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)

Comment: google documentation for this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/#debug-considerations

Answer (score 70):

### If your Android phone OS version 11 or above

Try this

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+

### Android 10 and below phones

**Step 1:** Goto your `Android sdk folder -> platform tools` and copy the whole path

**For example:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

**Step 2:** Goto command prompt or Android studio terminal

windows users `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

Mac Users `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

and press enter

**Step 3:** Connect your device & system with same wifi.

**Step 4:** Type `adb tcpip 5555` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Step 5:**  Type `adb connect x.x.x.x:5555`, replacing the **x.x.x.x** with your phone IP address.

**find out phone IP address**

`Settings -> About phone -> Status`  (some phones may be vary)

Note: In case that you connect more than one device, disconnect other phones except the one you need to connect.

**Command prompt screen shot:**
[image]

**For mac users -> if you face "adb command not found error" try this link**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017193/3879847

Comment: Path to Android SDK may be different. How to find out your path to Adnroid SDK: go to Settings, search "android sdk", copy path. My path it's C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: THE BEST ANSWER.. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: can anyone please tell me why sometimes sdk path did't works (step - 2), i mean in one project it works, while in another project it was not working..

Comment: after 4years.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 60):

Try below android studio plugin

[Android WiFi ADB](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2654)

**HOW TO**

1. Connect your device to your computer using a USB cable.
2. Then press the button [image: picture of a button to be pressed] on the toolbar and disconnect your USB once the plugin connects your device over WiFi.
3. You can now deploy, run and debug your device using your WiFi connection.

Github Link: https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB

**NOTE:** Remember that your device and your computer have to be in the same WiFi connection.

Comment: It works nice, but its a little bit slower, plus not logging  logs from the package. Its that normal?

Comment: is it that I have to connect by usb everytime ? or there's a permanent solution

Comment: Great tool.  I have just used it. It works great.  My computer is not on Wi-Fi, but it is on the same LAN as the Android device.

Comment: Why android studio throw error Plugin "ADB WIFI Debug LAN / WAN network" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: It appears as though this plugin is archived and no longer being maintaned

Comment: Plugin error: Plugin 'Android WiFi ADB' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Answer (score 15):

I used the following steps to successfully debug over wifi connection. I **recommend** this solution to **everybody experiencing problems** using integrated solutions like ***Android WiFi ADB* plugin**. In my case it failed to keep the Wifi connection to my device after unplugging USB. The following solution overcomes this problem.

## 1. Connecting device

### a. Connecting device using local wlan

If you have a local wlan you can connect your android device and your pc to this wlan.
Then identify the IP address of the android device by looking into its wlan settings.

### b. Connecting device directly using a hotspot

I prefer to connect with a hotspot on the device. This is more private and does not open your debugging connection to the (public) wlan.

1. Create a Wifi hotspot on the Android device
2. Connect PC to hotspot
3. On PC look into network connection status of this hotspot connection to find the *IPADDRESS* of your device.
   My system showed *IPADDRESS* `192.168.43.1`

## 2. Create debugging connection

1. Connect your device to USB.
2. Issue command `adb tcpip 5555` to open a port on the device for adb connection.
3. Create wireless debugging connection `adb connect IPADDRESS`.
    In my case the command looked like `adb connect 192.168.43.1`

The command `adb devices -l` should now display two devices if everything is ok. For example:

```
List of devices attached
ZY2244N2ZZ             device product:athene model:Moto_G__4_ device:athene
192.168.43.1:5555      device product:athene model:Moto_G__4_ device:athene
```

## 3. Keeping debugging connection

The tricky part comes when unplugging the USB connection. In my case both connections are closed immediately! This may not be the case for all users. For me this was the reason that I could not use *Android WiFi ADB* plugin for android studio.
I solved the problem by manually reconnecting the Wifi after unplugging usb by

```
adb connect 192.168.43.1
```

After that `adb devices -l`shows a single wifi connected device. This devices shows also up in android studio and can then be selected for debugging. When the connection is unstable you may need to repeat the above command from time to time to reactivate the connection.

Answer (score 13):

Try to run:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.2.4
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless

Comment: adb connects. Android Studio doesn't

Answer (score 7):

Android wifi ADB was earlier working on my IDE but after Updating Android Studio (my current is Android Studio 3.3) it is not working and always prompt as "Unable to connect to device......Same network"

After spending much time i was unbale to resolve the issue.

Then i tried - **WIFI ADB ULTIMATE** by

https://github.com/huazhouwang/WIFIADB/tree/master/WIFIADBIntelliJPlugin

It worked for me.

Edit: Now I am using ADB Wi-Fi, which is the simplest and easy-to-use plugin in Android Studio.

[image: ADB Wi-Fi Android Studio plugin]

Answer (score 6):

You can find information relating to setting up a device over WiFi over by the [Android ADB Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb).
For devices running Android 11+ see [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+).
For devices running Android 10- see [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless)

Comment: My Android device provides the WiFi hotspot and when I try to turn on "Wireless debugging" I get toast "Please connect to WiFi nerwork"!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to restart your adb via Android Studio (do it twice for good measure).

[image: resetting adb]

Answer (score 4):

0pen android studio and follow this path

> Go to -> settings -> plugins ->  Click on Browser repositories

after that search for **WIFI ADB ULTIMATE**  then click on install.

First time you have to connect it using USB.

You can check its working on github. For more details kindly refer [WIFI ADB ULTIMATE](https://github.com/huazhouwang/WIFIADB/tree/master/WIFIADBIntelliJPlugin)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a rooted phone then try this application [WiFi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en).

Probably this is the most simplest way to debug on wifi.

I am using this application from many days and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are simple steps to implement Android App debugging using ADB over wifi:**

> Required: You need to connect android device and computer to the same
>   router via wifi. You can use Android Wifi tethering also.

**Step 1:** Connect Android device via USB **(with developer mode enabled)**, and check its connection via `adb devices`.

**Step 2:** Open cmd/terminal and the path of your **../sdk/platform-tools**.

**Step 3:** Execute command `adb devices`.

**Step 4:** Execute command `adb -d` shell *(for device)* **OR** `adb -e shell` *(for emulator)*. Here you will get the shell access to the device.

**Step 5:** Execute command `ipconfig` (Windows command) or `ifconfig` (Linux command) and check the ip-address of it.

**Step 6:** Not disconnect/remove device USB and execute command `adb tcpip 5000`, to open tcpip socket port 5000 for adb debugging. You can open it on any port which is not currently occupied.

**Step 7:** Now execute command `adb connect <ip-address>:<port>`.  eg: `adb connect 192.168.1.90:5000` (where ip-address is device's wifi address and port which you have opened).

Now, run `adb device` and check the debugging device is now connected wirelessly via wifi.

Happy Coding...!

Comment: Shouldn't it be port 5555 instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using AS 3.2.1, and was about to try some of the plugins, but was hesitant realizing the plugins are able to monitor any data..

It's actually really simple doing it via the Terminal tab in AS:

1. Turn on debugging over WiFi in your phone

   - Go to developer options and turn on "ADB over network"
   - You'll see the exact address and port to use when connecting
2. Go to the Terminal tab in Android Studio
3. Type `adb tcpip 5555`
4. Type your ip address as seen in developer options i.e. `adb connect 192.168.1.101`
5. Now you'll see your device in AS "Select deployment target" dialog

Comment: I couldn't find this on my phone :  "ADB over network" Can it be somewhere else or under some other options?

Comment: It should be under developer options, you'll need to enable them first. Did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Got this error? [image]
Most of you are here because you didn't do the first thing that is:
1.Connect our Phone with the PC 
2.Keep both PC and device connected to the same WiFi
Then follow all the mentioned steps above.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully debug app through WiFi by following the [official site's guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless).

Note,

- WiFi debugging in Android 11+ is different from Android 10 and lower.
- Please update your adb, i.e. **Android SDK Platform-tools** to the latest version, otherwise you may miss some adb commands like `adb pair`.

Answer (score 2):

***if adb command not found.***

**-----------------------------**

Install homebrew

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Install adb

```
brew install android-platform-tools
```

**---------------------------**

***Connect the device now.***

- Enable **USB debugging in the Android device**
- Enable **Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode**
- Connect the device to the computer via a USB port.

Start using adb

```
adb devices
```

List of devices attached
**DUM0219A21000314  device**

the first item is **device id**.

```
adb -s <device id> tcpip 5555

adb -s DUM0219A21000314 tcpip 5555
```

**restarting in TCP mode port: 5555**

Find the local IP address of your Android device. You can find this information in the quick settings drop-down menu by pressing / long pressing the WiFi icon and then clicking on the WiFi network you are connected to.

```
adb connect <IP address>:5555
adb connect 192.168.2.2:5555
```

**connected to 192.168.2.2:5555**

Don't forget!
**Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode**
enabled before connecting the device

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.0.1 > Goto > (**Short cut key  (Alt+Cltr+S)**) Settings > Goto Plugins > Click on Browser repositories... > Search "**ADB WIFI**" and install the plugin. After the installation restart your android studio.

[image]

Click the icon [image] and connect your device.

Comment: any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers so far, is missing one VERY important step, otherwise you will get "connection refused" when trying to connect.

**Step 1:**
First enable Developer Options menu on your device, by navigating to the *About* menu on your device, then tapping the Build menu 5 times.

**Step 2:**
Then go to the now visible *Developer Options* menu and enable **USB debugging**.  Yes its a bit odd that you need this for Wifi debuging, but trust me, this is required.

**Step 3:**

> adb connect [your devices ip address]

It should say that you're now connected

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way is with Plugin Android WiFi ADB:

**For Android Studio Artic Fox|2020.3.1 Patch 2**

- Open Android Studio. Go to File/Setting/Plugins and Click on the
  MarketPlace. Search for Android Wifi ADB and install it.
- The plugin(AndroidWiFiADB) would be installed at path ->
  C:\Users\PCUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio\Plugins.
- Cut the Android Wifi ADB Folder.
- Now Paste That AndroidWiFiADB Folder at path -> C:\Program
  Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins
- Restart Android Studio And Icon Appears on The Right Side of The IDE .

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution, this directly connects Android 11 device to traditional 5555 port rather following new pairing strategy with different port everytime

Comment: Glad to know that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On `Windows`, save the following lines as xyz.bat

```
@echo off
adb tcpip 5555
set /p IP="IP Address: "
adb connect %IP%
EXIT /B 0
```

Run the script, put device IP and you're done!

Comment: where `xyz.bat` should be located !?

Comment: Wherever you want!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in newer version of AndroidStudio which allows you to test app on physical device over WiFi.

Please follow this official post: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#wireless

Answer (score -1):

just open settings / plugins / search " Android wifi adb and download it and connect your mobile using usb cabble once and its done

Comment: This solution is already given in previous answers with detailed steps.