# Android WIFI ADB plugin not working with some Android real device?

Tags: android, performance, debugging, wifi

I currently facing  this issue with all **MOTOROLA devices**.
Devices Name are:- MOTO e4 plus and MOTO-X play.
i currently use this **Plug-In (Android WIFI ADB)** for wifi debugging.
please suggest me if another Plug-In or any another way for  is available for WIFI debugging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For wifi debugging, you have to connect mobile via USB and enable USB debugging.
Then type `adb tcpip 5555`
This will enable wifi adb
Then you have to connect to device using command `adb connect IP_address_of_mobile`

P.S This method is needed only if your phone is not rooted. If your phone is rooted, you can directly type `tcpip 5555` from the phone itself.

Comment: Sangeet thanks ,
for the answer but, facing same issue  and  found same  answer from his link:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881295/5995648 after following the steps   android studio terminal give me  connected message   but  i can't found my device in wifi debugging.

Comment: yes,actually i connect only one device but it saw 2 devices one with highlighted text and another one is light grey. is that means my devices is connect with wifi debugging?

Comment: Yes if adb devices command is showing your device, it's connected to pc

Comment: Remove usb cable and try adb devices command, if it is showing 1 device, you can run without connecting cable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170562/discussion-between-arbaz-in-and-sangeet-suresh).

Comment: Will this process make our device vulnerable if we always use it like this?