# Android Things Project with Empty Activity on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I just downloaded an Android Things Image and flashed a SD-Card for the Raspberry PI 3 Model B, ok, it worked. I connected the Rasperry to my Network and created an "Android Things Empty Activity" with a TextView "Hello World".

First thing, the Android Studio did not connected to the PI. After downloading "platform-tools" and running in Windows Command cmd "adb connect android.local" I am able to download the App to the PI. I am using the Raspberry Pi Touch Display https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/.

Second thing, the touch behavior is not very well, in my opinion it dosent work.

Third thing, after downloading the app. The app does not start, only after clicking a button "profile app" or restarting the PI with power off/on :(

Fourth things, after the app finaly starts: I guess it is empty!? Only the DarkActionBar is visible with the Text in strings.xml. Whatever I place in main_activity.xml, it looks like I am in the wrong xml file.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First thing, the Android Studio did not connected to the PI

you can use debug over WiFi connection like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33726622/6950238) question.

> Second thing, the touch behavior is not very well, in my opinion it
>   dosent work.

take a look at [that](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/70846/59288) question and answer. Use screens with less resolutions and write custom drivers for touch panel.

> after downloading the app. The app does not start

It's normal behavior. You should not only upload the application to Pi, but also run it in some way: reboot device or start it manually by `adb` command like that:

`adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName`

(debug over WiFi connection from "First thing" also will help)

> Fourth things

It's hard to help you without the source code.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, very helpful. And I found number 4: In my Android.Manifest I added the following the to the activity tag: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`