# 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, command-line, adb

I have set the environmental variables as:

[image]

and

[image]

as well as added them to the path, which calling `echo %path%`:

[image]

yet calling `adb` from command still yields the error:

`'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Silly question, but your 'platform-tools' folder does contain adb, right? That folder hasn't been modified in any way? What happens when you call adb from inside the platform-tools folder?

Comment: it is present. Calling "adb" works there

Comment: remove the spaces after `;` in your `%PATH%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the user variable you added
System Variable PATH
Variable name : PATH
Variable Value : C:\Users\KJA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
open a new terminal try echo %path%

restart android studio and try adb on android studio terminal

Comment: I did that, nothing changed. Do I need to restart?

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303639/adb-command-not-found

Comment: and make sure you are pointing out the correct directory in variable value.. nope no need for restart

Comment: ok i got it working now edit the  system variable name PATH and make the value to where until platform-tools where adb is located  and dont add it on user variables after that restart android studio

Comment: That is what I am doing. adb is located within the file `platform-tools`

Comment: can you show me the variable name and the value please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108678/discussion-between-sauron-and-dione-llorera).