# How to set adb connections for NOX player on Mac OS

Tags: android, react-native

I need to set nox emulator as my default emulator, but I need to set first adb connection, but I don't know where I can find the directory of nox app player.

Answer (score 6):

Fortunately, as a Mac user, you don't have to worry too much about the directory of the Nox app player, because you don't have to use the executable ***nox_adb.exe***, as do Windows users. Instead, you can, with a slight change, [follow the steps in the Nox connection guide](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/), but just look out, as a Mac user, for step 6, (according to  [*vandebergz*](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=578792e921b9045237b00c99be5ef1fc&p=70627221&postcount=4)) :

1. Download & install Nox.
2. Start a project in Android Studio.
3. Start Nox App Player, and in Nox go to Nox system settings and turn
   **root mode** to on, then save changes and restart Nox.
4. In Nox, go to Android settings  and scroll down to *About Tablet*. Keep clicking on *Build number* until it shows that, "*You are now a developer*". In Android settings the *Developer options* will now be visible.
5. In *Developer options*, tick *USB debugging*.
6. (*Mac only*) Depending on whether or not *adb* and other tools are in your *PATH* (see below), type
   `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001`
   from a suitable location. (This will connect *localhost* through port 62001 to the Android Debug Bridge.)
7. Android Studio should now detect Nox Player as a connectable device (although it may not appear named as Nox).

Please bear in mind that for this to work, if you're using Android Studio with default installation settings, you should either do step 6 from the directory of *adb* , which is usually *~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools* ; or else you can do this from *any* location if you have *adb* and the other platform tools on your *PATH*. To add them to your *PATH*, if not done already, you'll need to open your hidden *~/.bash_profile* file and add the lines:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

[as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574922/11365317).

Worked ok for me. :)

Comment: In mac, I didnt even run step 6. I did `adb devices` and the Nox device was already connected.

Comment: In mac, just setup adb , activate developer mode (tick usb debugging on) and run adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001. That's it.